# multilingual support

Tags: theming, 7

I would like to create a content type in Drupal 7, which is available in both Italian and English. This is why I enabled multilingual support in the options of publications that allows me to choose the creation of each new node language.
But...How do I then change the choice of language in which I see the node in the web pages?

Answer (score 2):

You need [i18n](http://drupal.org/project/i18n) module. It gives you a possibility to display a language switcher block on the front end.

Also check [Localization update](http://drupal.org/project/l10n_update) module for automatic update of translations.